# Magento 2 Associate Developer Exam

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

I'm starting to prepare for the **Magento 2 Associate Developer Exam.**
Can you help with some tips for this preparation?
Some **books, tests, sites** or something else?
 Thank you very much.

Comment: question shows no effort.